# Have a maven build output full class names of annotated classes to resource file

Tags: java, maven, annotations

In my project, I'd like to have a resource file at the root of my JAR containing fully qualified names of classes that have a given annotation. Is this possible? Support for multiple annotations would be excellent.

Comment: What's the problem? Can you paste the error?

Comment: @guisantogui Are you sure that response goes with this question? It feels a little off center :)

Comment: I don't think there's much out there to do what you're looking for. I'd suggest writing a simple plugin. Easy enough.